# Eclipse editor not showing "case sensitive", "regular expressions", "word search"

Tags: eclipse, find

I'm using Eclipse on Debian Linux. The find window stopped showing the case sensitive, word boundry and regular expressions options.  I've looked at editor preferences and reset the window perspective for an option and can't find one.  What happened?  How do I turn these options back on?

Thanks
Steve S.

[image: findImageWindow]

This is the window I see now.

**FIXED** -- @flafoux suggested resizing the window and that fixed the problem.

Comment: This window is sizeable, try to elarge it (might sound stupid but lots of people had this problem solved like this)

Comment: Ahh -- thank you @flafoux.  Never even thought of that!